# Error Encountered When Running Test Cases in Ballerina: Failed to Start Debug Adapter

Tags: ballerina

I am encountering an issue when running ballerina test cases in my project. This occurs even for a simple test case.

```
Import ballerina/test;

@test:Config {}
function test() {
    test:assertEquals(10, 10);
}
```

However, when I run this test case, I receive an error message and I’m unable to debug the code. The error message is as follows:

```
Starting debug adapter: 'bal.bat start-debugger-adapter 10001
Debug server started on 10001
error: Failed to start debug adapter due to: com/sun/jdi/connect/IllegalConnectorArgumentsException
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try `bal test --code-coverage`.

There's a known issue on Windows.